# Dynamic Layout Creation inside on Focus change

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to add some fields (textview, edit and checkbox) dynamically  to a tablelayout on focus change of edittext which is already present and visible. I need to validate the text scanned and if validated need to populate the views below for user to scan....

Could please suggest a good way to go about this? I have written the onfocus change validation  logic.. but unable to manipulate the tablelayout within  focus change

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: so you want that if edit text filed is valid then other control should be view or add dynamic else not ? am i right ?

Comment: i need to add new elements when entered is valid else no...

Comment: that is conditional base if the entered data is valid then add new element else not. so why and where you getting problem in this ?